# Is there "array_search"-like function for a simplexml object

Tags: php, codeigniter, simplexml

I have a codeigniter app that queryies an api and gets a simplexml object.  I had hard coded the values I wanted from the simplexml object, but found out later that the structure of the object isn't always the same, so I can't use casting to get the values I need.

Is there an array_search like function that I could use for this so I can use the "classid" to get the value?  Here is a sampling of the simplexml object:

```
    [Package] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [ID] => e981b9a72cd305c7d97cc530ef9b3015
            )

        [Postage] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [CLASSID] => 3
                            )

                        [MailService] => Express Mail<sup>&reg;</sup>
                        [Rate] => 57.60
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [CLASSID] => 2
                            )

                        [MailService] => Express Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> Hold For Pickup
                        [Rate] => 57.60
                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [CLASSID] => 55
                            )

                        [MailService] => Express Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> Flat Rate Boxes
                        [Rate] => 39.95
                    )
```

I was using this to get the [Rate] value:

```
$usps->Package->Postage[0]->Rate
```

The problem is  I need to use [CLASSID] because that is consistant where the data in the number key(?) changes.

Comment: Could you post the XML you used to generate that output?

Comment: XPath may be what you are after

Comment: Thanks tandu, you are right!  I was able to get what I wanted with this:    $usps->xpath('//Postage[@CLASSID="3"]');

Comment: @tandu you should post that as an answer, I pretty much use Xpath exclusively when reading XML documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

You can not only search for specific elements, but do all kinds of crazy searches using various axes.

Comment: @tandu answered this in a previous comment - Thanks tandu, you are right! I was able to get what I wanted with this: $usps->xpath('//Postage[@CLASSID="3"]');

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I have no way of testing it without the raw XML:

```
$rates = array();

foreach ($usps->Package->Postage as $postage)
    $rates[$postage->attributes()->CLASSID] = $postage->Rate;
```